# production credentials with Angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm putting all my credentials into `environments/environment.prod.ts` in my Angular 6 app, it works great, but it will also be available on Github.

Should I put the file on .gitignore, or is there something better to do?

Comment: There is no need to commit confidential credentials in `environments/environment.prod.ts` file in a public Github repository. You can just add dummy credentials while committing the code. If it is in company's internal repository, then this article may help you: https://medium.com/@natchiketa/angular-cli-and-os-environment-variables-4cfa3b849659

Comment: @SaddamPojee this is a bad approach. See https://12factor.net/config

Answer (score 0):

you can use `git-secret`

> git-secret is a bash tool which stores private data inside a git repo. git-secret encrypts tracked files with public keys for users whom you trust using gpg, allowing permitted users to access encrypted data using their secret keys. With git-secret, changes to access rights are made easy and private-public key issues are handled for you. Passwords do not need to be changed with git-secret when someone's permission is revoked - just remove their key from the keychain using git secret killperson their@email.com, and re-encrypt the files, and they won't be able to decrypt secrets anymore.

Reference: http://git-secret.io

or git-crypt

> git-crypt enables transparent encryption and decryption of files in a git repository. Files which you choose to protect are encrypted when committed, and decrypted when checked out. git-crypt lets you freely share a repository containing a mix of public and private content. git-crypt gracefully degrades, so developers without the secret key can still clone and commit to a repository with encrypted files. This lets you store your secret material (such as keys or passwords) in the same repository as your code, without requiring you to lock down your entire repository.

Reference: https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt

Comment: this doesn't help, because even if the credentials are encrypted, they have to be decrypted at build time/run time